# Process sequence of maps in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the sequence of maps

```
(def aaa '({:a "read"} {:a "open"}) )
```

I am needed to get following sequence of values

```
("read" "open")
```

What way can I do it in clojure?

Comment: Have you read the docs?  Or tried anything?  This is pretty basic Clojure.

Comment: Keywords are functions so `(map :a aaa)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @jmargolisvt mentioned, this is pretty straightforward. If you haven't worked through something like braveclojure.com then I highly recommend it, just to get the feel for basic functional programming with Clojure.

```
(def aaa '({:a "read"} {:a "open"}) )
(map :a aaa)
```

Edit: Just wanted to expand a little to provide a little more than a polite RTFM. keywords can be functions that operate on maps. If your keyword is not in the list, then it will return `nil`, so if you had

```
(def bbb '({:a "read"} {:a "open"} {:b "scribble") )
```

and you wanted to get only the `:a` values and no the resulting `nil` value, then you would first want to `filter` the sequence.

```
(map :a 
     (filter #(contains? % :a) bbb))
```